# Editing multiple lines that don't look identical

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am just getting into vscode and am trying to edit multiple lines in the following way. My input is:

```
{"lng": -120.85,"lat": 35.533333},
{"lng": -120.116667,"lat": 35.75},
{"lng": -119.5,"lat": 35.633333},
{"lng": -119.166667,"lat": 36.133333},
```

The output should be:

```
poly.Add(geo.NewPoint(-120.85, 35.533333))
poly.Add(geo.NewPoint(-120.116667, 35.75))
poly.Add(geo.NewPoint(-119.5, 35.633333))
poly.Add(geo.NewPoint(-119.166667, 36.133333))
```

Now should I just try to use find/replace - which might be difficult - or is there another way that vscode could do this? In vim I would have used macros for this, but as I said I am pretty new to vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^\{"lng": ([^,]+),"lat": ([^}]+)\},$
Replace: poly.Add(geo.NewPoint($1, $2))
```

### Demo

This approach uses a regex pattern which matches each input line, in the process capturing the latitude and longitude values in `$1` and `$2`.  Then, the replacement uses these capture values to generate the code output you want.

Comment: Thank you! This not only works, but shows that there is still a lot to learn... Great solution!